# break a slide of reveal.js (xaringan) when it's long

Tags: slideshow, r-markdown, reveal.js, bibliography

I'm actually using [xaringan](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan), but it uses reveal.js, so it should be the same.

I have a slide which prints bibliography using RefManageR, and I'd like to use as many slides as needed:

````
---

```
{r results = "asis", echo = FALSE}
PrintBibliography(bib, .opts = list(check.entries = FALSE, sorting = "ynt"))

```
---
````

I guess I'm looking for some type of allowframebreaks, but I couldn't manage to find one.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237862/best-way-to-handle-overflowing-reveal-js-slide

Comment: Thanks! I'll use that in the meanwhile!

Comment: The problem with this is when I convert the slides to PDFs :(. I haven't found a way to break the frames yet.

Comment: And using Chrome to print them as PDF is not sufficient?

Comment: no, I just see a slide with a slidebar that of course you can move in the pdf

Answer (score 3):

Xaringan uses remark.js, not reveal.